# Why can't I make a WinForms app register for COM interop?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

I'm using Visual Studio 2015. I have successfully created a class library and selected:

```
Register form COM Interop
Make Assembly COM-visible
```

I've then managed to deploy this using a Setup Project to other users and it works great (although still don't understand why Intellisense doesn't work for it)

Now I'm trying to do the same for a WinForms application, but

```
Register form COM Interop
```

is not viable to apply, it's grayed out - should it be? And if so, why can't I register an application for COM Interop so I can manipulate it in other apps? (e.g. in Excel VBA)

Comment: It is a bit arbitrary, a good practice, you could run Regasm.exe and it will work just fine.  But your Main() entrypoint won't run so the app doesn't behave normally.  .NET does not support out-of-process COM servers.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for that idea, I wouldn't want my users to have to run Regasm - I've discovered to create everything in a class library and run a setup project from visual studio. With the help of another answer somewhere I've just even discovered how to make my libraries use intellisense so I can get users to code using my classes easily. One of your answers helped out there too, thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that com registration normally makes only sense for assemblies (.dlls) and your WinForm application is normally a executable (.exe).

So I this case you should create a dll and move all the functions and classes that should be com visible into this assembly. Than make it Com visible and use it also from your executbale WinForms application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I sorta figured that as I made a new class library and it was fine with putting forms in there... just seems that a default winFormApp won't allow it - I think I understand why now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To register a .NET assembly for COM Interop, the assembly has to be a *class library*, which is intended to be **shared** by applications.

A WinForms application, on the other hand, runs as a standalone program is not intended to be shared by other applications.

In this case, you can create a class library project, and creates a WinForms **UserControl** in the project, and expose the `UserControl` to other apps by making it COM visible.

Here is an [old example](https://www.telerik.com/support/kb/winforms/details/wrapping-a-net-user-control-as-an-activex), strangely it is hard to find more recent examples in my search.

Comment: So there's no way I can create an .exe file that could be harnessed by COM. The reason I'm asking is I'd like to code a password into an app on a secure online area that people can send info via. I can create as many libraries as I want but I really need my client-side app to access the server-hosted app and was hoping it could do this via COM... but I don't think it's possible.

Comment: You can ask a new question for this requirement, there can be different possible ways to fulfill the requirement, not necessarily a COM thing.